# How to choose the value of nu parameter in one class SVM data without outliers

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

> The nu parameter is an upper bound on the
> fraction of training errors and a lower bound of the fraction of
> support vectors.

I quote from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_anomaly_comparison.html) :

> This estimator is best suited for novelty detection when the training set is not contaminated by outliers.

This is exactly my case. I have a dataset of 2000 labeled samples (Class 0).

I want to train my `oneclassSVM` model on this dataset, then try to predict 200 unlabeled unseen samples whether they belong to class 0 or not.

In this case, when training the model, the nu parameter should be 0, right ? Because I don't have any outliers in my training data. But, this is not even possible because its value should be in the interval (0, 1]

Can someone clarify to me how do we correctly choose the value of nu?
And how could we train a model with positive data only?